# Latest N scores by ID (AKA rows to columns by ID)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have as my data a list of IDs that track scores over time like so:

```
ID | Score | Timestamp
1  | 50    | 09/23/17
1  | 45    | 09/30/17
1  | 43    | 10/07/17
1  | 46    | 10/14/17
2  | 35    | 09/30/17
2  | 41    | 10/07/17
2  | 40    | 10/14/17
3  | 12    | 10/07/17
3  | 18    | 10/14/17
```

Most IDs have dozens of entries, but newer ones might have as few as one or two.

I want to generate a table of scores by ID using this table, like so:

```
ID | Latest Score | 2nd Latest Score | ...
1  | 46           | 43               | 45   | 50
2  | 40           | 41               | 35   | NULL
3  | 18           | 12               | NULL | NULL
```

So the cell for latest score for ID 1 would either scan the data for the last row with ID 1 or the latest date for ID 1 (they're the same), then return the corresponding score (46).

I'm having trouble figuring out how to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use Pivot table to achieve the same.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Pivots are good for a quick solution but best avoided when you can

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Try this **array formula** (click `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` together inside formula bar):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(LARGE(IF(($A$2:$A$10=$E2)*($C$2:$C$10),($A$2:$A$10=$E2)*($C$2:$C$10),""),COLUMN(F2)-COLUMN($E2)),($A$2:$A$10=$E2)*($C$2:$C$10),0)),"")
```

Basically, I used `LARGE` to return the latest score (based on Timestamp but let me know if this is wrong) and the `INDEX/MATCH` to lookup for the value to return.  Try and see if this makes sense to you or let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Beat me to the punch! Nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using an array formula and `Index`, `Match`, `Large` and `If` you can get your answer out and avoid pivot tables
Entered into cell `E2`

```
=IFNA(INDEX($B$2:$B$10, MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$10=$E2)*($C$2:$C$10=(LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$10=$E2,$C$2:$C$10),COLUMN()-COLUMN($E2)))),0)),"")
```

Entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

To break this down:

- Firstly we `INDEX` the range that we want to return using `INDEX($B$2:$B$10`
- Next we `MATCH` our criteria. There is two parts to this.

  - We want to match two criteria so we are going to create two arrays to match our criteria, multiply them together and evaluate to 1

    - Our first criteria is to match the ID. We do this using `($A$2:$A$10=$E2)`
    - The second criteria is to get the correct date. `($C$2:$C$10=(LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$10=$E2,$C$2:$C$10),COLUMN()-COLUMN($E2))))` We do this by using `LARGE(IF` to return just the ID's that we are interested with from the range. And then select the largest number using `COLUMN()-COLUMN($E2)` This selects the biggest, second biggest etc.

Putting this all together returns our output

### Output:

[image: Results]